# Difference between NuGet packages and extensions

Tags: visual-studio, nuget-package, visual-studio-extensions

In Visual Studio under Tools menu, what is the difference between "NuGet Package Manager" -> "Manage NuGet Packages for Solution..." and "Extensions and Updates..." ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Nuget packages are project-specific and travel through source control to your colleagues. An installed extension works in all your *own* solutions/projects and doesn't get shared.

Comment: This is undeniably correct, although I wonder _why_ one couldn't create a NuGet package that works in the same way as an extension. I appreciate that the current VS doesn't support it, and neither does NuGet itself, but I do think it makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 0):

Extension Manager installs extension which extends the Visual Studio meanwhile NuGet NuGet package manager helps developer to add, update and delete the external library (Packages) and their dependency in your application. Also you can create package from GuNet and share to the world.